Align image with text in the same fashion as flex with inline-block
I am trying to vertically center align an image with text using inline-block. I am doing this because I want the icon to always wrap with the first line of text as the text wraps to a new line as opposed to to it center aligning with the whole block.
The problem I'm running into is that when everything is on a single line, vertical-align: middle doesn't seem to vertically center images in the same fashion that display: flex and align-items: center does. As a result this ends up with things looking inconsistent when I need to interchange between the two. I've attached screenshots, as you can see the top of the first letter is slightly different between the two approaches.
Is there a way to do what the first example is doing with flex box instead so I can have things vertically center in the same nature? Right now they are slightly off if you compare the two closely. If not, how do I reconcile these differences in the alignment?




.example-a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 24px;

}

.example-a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 42px;
}

.example-b {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}
<div class="example-a">
  <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/starstruck-default--light-a594e2a027e0.png">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et molestie nulla. Ut ut augue id mi porttitor scelerisque.</span>
</div>

<div class="example-b">
  <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/starstruck-default--light-a594e2a027e0.png">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et molestie nulla. Ut ut augue id mi porttitor scelerisque.</span>
</div>




Is there a way to do what the first example is doing with flex box? No, it's impossible to achieve that using flex. Each element inside of flex parent has its own reserved space that no other sibling can cross.

Somewhat assumed that to be the case. How do I reconcile the differences between the vertical alignments?

You could try giving the text it's own parent div and applying padding. That should center the text in relation to the container.

Not sure I'm following. Offsets aren't ideal because it's going to just cause additional issues if the text size changes.
